# How to get the default value from an XmlSchema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm working with an XmlSchema object which was initialized with an XSD file.
The XSD file contains some validation rules (type, min, max, etc.. ) and some of the elements have a default value attribute.

Here is a short example:

1. the XML file:

```
<person>
    <first>john</first>
    <last>doe</last>
    <age>50</age>
</person>
```

The XML is being loaded in an XmlDocument object.

2. The XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="person" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name ="first" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name ="last" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name ="age" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" default="30"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XSD is being loaded to an XmlSchema object.

3. I want to retrieve the default value for age without performing validation and regular XML parsing, and if I have to perform validation, how can I retrieve the value if the node was validated successfully (the validation handler is not being called when it succeeds)?

I tried to get the values with `IXmlSchemaInfo.SchemaElement`, but it is set to null after the validation occurred.

OK, some clarifications:

The default value means the default value when the user did not assign the age element. The XML could have been:

```
<person>
    <first>john</first>
    <last>doe</last>
    <age></age>
</person>
```

I'll try to be more precise:

1. I have three text boxes, txtFirst, txtLast, and txtAge.
2. I have a data object with three properties. First, Last and Age.
3. The text boxes are bound to the data object which is being initialized based on the XML file, so when there is no value for "age", I want to retrieve it from the schema

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by `default value`, lowest valid value as allowed by the schema? It seems the xml already has a value. Please provide actual schema and actual xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is a code sample on how to traverse an `XmlSchema` object on MSDN: *[Traversing XML Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255932%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)*.

This way you can read the value of the `default` attribute of the given elements.

Comment: and if i want to get a specific schema element without traversing the whole schema ? (may be with linq ?? )

Comment: You could load the xsd as an XDocument and run LINQ-to-XML against it, but I'm not used to LINQ-to-XML, so I cannot give you an example here. There is also a install from 2006(!) called LINQ-to-XSD http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=23589

Comment: Just found a more current version of LINQ-to-XSD on CodePlex: http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/